# how to display lightning components inside a sf1 app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning

Hi I am using  Lightning components inside a Visualforce page. And I'm trying to display the visualforce page on the sf1 app by creating a action  button. I created a action button, type- custom visualforcepage , and linked it to a Visualforce page that has lightning components.

I have edited the Accounts object page layout. I have added this action button to the salesforce1 and  Lightning Experience Actions section on the accounts  object layout.

In the sf1 app, when I click on the button  just now i added to layout, the  visual force page is not correctly displaying the lightning components . I need to set the width and height of this visualforcepage to the view size of the sf1 app.so that the contents are displayed correctly. For now I have used the mobile design templates in my visualforce page

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/08/getting-started-with-mobile-design-templates.html

Can anyone let me know how to display the contents of the lightning components with out any errors  in the Visualforce page.? As of now I can't clearly view buttons , labels, fields.

Comment: If you have lightning component ,you can directly use lightning tabs to create your tab for SF1 or use app builder to build lightning page